# Popover from UIButton very slow on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

Scenario:

UIScrollView has a UIButton. Tapping the UIButton leads to a UIPopoverController presenting itself from a specified rect. The UIPopoverController's contentViewController is a UIViewController with a UIDatePicker.

Code that is fired when the button is tapped (button is of type custom with touch up inside tap registered):

```
- (void)showCalendar:(id)sender {
    dateViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 200)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];

    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(DateChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSLocale *US = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setLocale:US];
    [datePicker setCalendar:cal];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];


    dateViewController.view = datePicker;

    dateViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(240, 200);
    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                               initWithContentViewController:dateViewController];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"YESYESYES");

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(753, 513, 1, 1) inView:parentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"NONONO");

}
```

There is a noticeable 1 second or more lag between the two NSLog statements when I connect the device to Xcode and run the app. What could be the reason for such a lag?

Comment: Could it be in a background thread instead of the main thread? If you have an `IBAction` calling this method, place the method inside of GCD main queue.

Comment: Nope. It runs on the main thread.

Comment: When the button is pressed, is this the method called? Or is this method called from another method? (i.e. an IBAction or something else)

Comment: Also, check my answer below. Just to humor me, can you try putting the `NSLog` statements and the `presentPopover` code into GCD as I show in the example? What is the delay after you do that?

Comment: Strange issue, strange solution. Are you using iOS 6 beta ?  I have the same problem but loading the controller from the storyboard. My popover also contains a date picker but your solution does not apply to my case. If you have any idea of the root cause, please let me know.

Comment: @smad No. I am using it on iOS 5.1. I will let you know if there is some other generic issue. But in my case I am able to reproduce it every time I use someViewController.view = someOtherView. Can you post on what you are doing in code with your popover/datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issued by replacing

```
dateViewController.view = datePicker;
```

with

```
[dateViewController.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

Answer (score 1):

What queue are you running this method in?

To run it in the main queue, try this out. If you aren't using Interface Builder, replace the IB code with the appropriate code.

```
- (void)showCalendar:(id)sender {

    // your setup code here... then:

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"YESYESYES");
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(753, 513, 1, 1) inView:parentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"NONONO");
    });
}
```